# Uniqueness of high-dimensional derivative [Zorich's book]

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I was reading the definition of the high-dimensional derivative from Zorich's book and I'd like to ask a question about the uniqueness of high-dimensional derivative.

> **Definition 1.** A function $f:E\to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined on a set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^m$is *differentiable at the point* $x\in E$,
> which is a limit of $E$, if  $$f(x+h)-f(x)=L(x)h+\alpha(x;h), \quad \quad \quad(1)$$ where
> $L(x):\mathbb{R}^{m}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a function that is linear in
> $h$ and $\alpha(x;h)=o(h)$ as $h\to 0, x+h\in E$.
>
> The linear function $L(x):\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ in $(1)$ is
> called the  **differential** of the function $f:E\to
>  \mathbb{R}^n$ at the point $x\in E$.

**Claim.** If $E\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ and $f:E\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at the point $x\in E$, which is a limit point of $E$, then the differential of $f$ at the point $x\in E$ is unique.

*Proof.* Let's assume there are $A,B:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ linear mappings such that
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=Ah+\alpha(x;h) \quad \text{and} \quad f(x+h)-f(x)=Bh+\beta(x;h),$$ where $\alpha(x;h)=o(h)$ and $\beta(x;h)=o(h)$ as $h\to 0, x+h\in E$.

Remark. Here the base is $h\to 0, x+h\in E$. The elements of this base are $B_{\delta}:=\{h\in \mathbb{R}^m: 0\leq \lVert h\rVert<\delta, x+h\in E\}$ for $\delta>0$. Indeed, it satisfies to the definition of base.

Let $C:=A-B$, then $C:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear mapping also. Then it is not difficult to show that $$\lim \limits_{\substack{h\to 0 \\ x+h\in E}} \frac{\lVert Ch\rVert}{\lVert h\rVert}=0.$$

Let $y$ be a nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$. If we can show that $\lim \limits_{\substack{\mathbb{R}\ni t\to 0 \\ x+ty\in E}} \frac{\lVert C(ty)\rVert}{\lVert ty\rVert}=0,$ then we are done. Indeed, in that case it follows that $\lVert Cy\rVert=0$ for all $y\neq 0$, which implies that $Cy=0$ for all $y$ and hence $Ay=By$. Therefore, linear mappings $A$ and $B$ are equal.

**Question.** How to prove that if $\lim \limits_{\substack{h\to 0 \\ x+h\in E}} \frac{\lVert Ch\rVert}{\lVert h\rVert}=0$, then $\lim \limits_{\substack{\mathbb{R}\ni t\to 0 \\ x+ty\in E}} \frac{\lVert C(ty)\rVert}{\lVert ty\rVert}=0$ ??

It is certainly true if $x$ is an interior point of $E$ but it does not look correct to me because we claim that $x$ is the limit point of $E$. Let me try to explain why do I think so.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Take $\delta_0=\frac{\delta}{\lVert y\rVert}>0$, where $\delta>0$ comes from the first limit. Then for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0<|t|<\delta_0,\ x+ty\in E$ we'll get that $\frac{\lVert C(ty)\rVert}{\lVert ty\rVert}<\varepsilon$. It seems that we are done but how do we know that such $t$ exists?
I mean how do we know that $\{t\in \mathbb{R}: 0<|t|<\delta_0, x+ty\in E\}\neq \varnothing$?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: This question has been raised [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598676) and although it remains unanswered, it might be useful to you.

Comment: If you take $E$ a hyperplane and $y$ a normal vector then your limit looks odd: the function has an empty domain. Can't you let $E$ be open? He deserves it :)

Comment: @blamethelag, which limit are you talking about?

Comment: @ZFR the second one in your **Question**.

Comment: @kabenyuk, many thanks for your link! But let me ask you a few questions: **1)** if we define differentiability as Zorich did, then we ran into some trouble as a non-uniqueness of differential. Having many differentials at one point is a meaningless, right? **2)** Am I right that it is better to change the definition into the case when $E$ is open set or $x$ is an interior point of $E$? Thank you!

Comment: @kabenyuk **3)** Also if we define the differentiablity in the way as Zorich did for functions $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ with $E\subset \mathbb{R}$, then it is not an issue. I mean in that case, the differential is still unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a $t$ does not necessarily exist. You can take a hyperplane $E$ passing through the origin $ x = 0$ and $y$ any vector which spans a line which is not included in the hyperplane $E$. In this case one has

$$ x + ty \not \in E \quad  \forall t \in \mathbb R_0. $$

In this case we do not have unicity of the differential. Indeed consider $f = k \in \mathbb R$ constant on $E$.  Then $$ f(x + h) - f(x) = 0.$$
Hence it follows that any linear map $L_x : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R : h \mapsto L_x(h)$ whose restriction to the hyperplane $E$ is equal to $0$ satisfies the definition of differentiability.

---

> Your example is showing that if we assume that the function $f:E\to \mathbb R^n$ is differentiable at the point $x\in E$, where $x$ is a limit point of E, then differential of f at $x$ may not be unique, right?

Yes. However if the limit point $x$ happens to be an interior point then we do have unicity.

> To avoid this ambiguity one needs to assume that x is an interior point of E or E is an open set, right?

Not really. Asking that $x$ be an interior point garanties the unicity. But this is not needed in order to have unicity. Indeed it is possible ins some cases for $x$ to be a limit point, $x$ not an interior point and still have  unicity. That is, $x$ being an interior point is a sufficient condition but not needed.

**Example**

Let $E = [0,1]^2 \subset \mathbb R^2$ and $f = k \in \mathbb R$ be constant on $E$. Define

$$ L_x = 0 : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$$
Then for all $x  + h = h \in E$
$$f(x+h)-f(x) - L(x)h = 0 = o(h),$$
so $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$. To prove the unicity suppose there are other linear maps $A,B$ satisfying the definition then let $C = A-B$ and we have

$$ \lim_{h\to 0, x + h \in E} \frac{\Vert Ch \Vert}{\Vert h \Vert} = 0.$$

Let $y_1 = (1,0), y_2 = (0,1) \in E$. Then for all $0 < t < 1$ we have
$ x + ty_i \in E$ hence we have

$$ \lim_{t \to 0 , t > 0 }  \frac{\Vert C(ty_i) \Vert}{\Vert ty_i \Vert} = 0.$$

In particular we deduce that $$ A(y_i) = B(y_i).$$
Since the two linear maps $A$ and $B$ coincide on a basis of the vector space $\mathbb R^2$ it follows that $$ A = B.$$

> If we consider one-dimensional case, i.e. f:E→R where E⊂R and f is differentiable at x∈E, then in that setting we always have unicity of differential even x is a limit point of E, right? I think the subtle difference here is that in R we have only one direction

If we adapt our proof to the case where $E$ is of dimension one then yes that's the general idea. However for the case where $E \subset \mathbb R$ there is a much simpler argument to prove the unicity. Indeed there are linear maps $L_1,L_2$ and $\alpha_i(x;h) = o(h)$ such that
$$ f(x + h) - f(x) = L_i(x)h + \alpha_i(x;h)$$
then
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = L_i(x) $$
so $L_1 = L_2$ by unicity of the limit.

Comment: Let me ask you a few questions: **1)** Your example is showing that if we assume that the function $f:E\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at the point $x\in E$, where $x$ is a limit point of $E$, then differential of $f$ at $x$ may not be unique, right? **2)** To avoid this ambiguity one needs to assume that $x$ is an interior point of $E$ or $E$ is an open set, right?

Comment: P.S. By the way your example is exactly the same as in the link which @kabenyuk provided.

Comment: @ZFR I've edited my answer to address your comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a really good answer which I'll accept! But let me ask you two more questions: **3)** If we consider one-dimensional case, i.e. $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ where $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is differentiable at $x\in E$, then in that setting we always have unicity of differential even $x$ is a limit point of $E$, right? I think the subtle difference here is that in $\mathbb{R}$ we have only one direction.

Comment: **4)** However, in general case I think it is better to consider when $E$ is open set. Your examples have shown that if $x$ is a limit point of $E$, we may have unicity and may not. That is why it is meaningful to take $E\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ to be an open set. Right?

Comment: @ZFR Yes working over open sets is easier. This makes everything easier because when $x$ is in the interior you can approach $x$ from any direction. This gives you a lot a freedom in proofs so everything becomes easier. The fact the unicity of the derivative follows from this makes it even more practical to work over open sets. In fact most textbooks restrict themselves to open sets. Answer to **3)** is now in the edited post.

Comment: That was a really good and deep explanantion! Thank you so much for such a detailed answer! +1